# ctypes does not free string buffers?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I was curious, whether using the Windows API `HeapAlloc` (via `ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE`) or using `ctypes.create_string_buffer` is faster for allocating arrays of integers and I found some strange behavior when it comes to deallocating the buffers. Normally, when you create a string buffer

```
import ctypes
buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1024 * 1024 * 1024) # 1 GiB
```

and delete it later

```
del buffer
```

its memory is freed. You can see this by inspecting the process's memory usage. **But**, if you cast the buffer to, say, a pointer before deletion

```
buffer = ctypes.cast(buffer, ctypes.c_void_p) # also works with POINTER(...) instead of c_void_p
del buffer
```

the buffer's memory is no longer freed. This is strange, because the pointer knows about the buffer:

```
buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1024 * 1024 * 1024) # 1 GiB
ptr = ctypes.cast(buffer, ctypes.c_void_p)

ptr._objects      # -> {<some int> : <ctypes.c_char_Array_5 object at ...>}
buffer2 = list(ptr._objects.values())[0]
buffer2 is buffer # -> True

# Also works with POINTER(...) instead of c_void_p
```

Is this expected behavior? To me it seems like someone forgot to `Py_DECREF(b_objects)` somewhere in `PyCSimpleType` or `PyCPointerType`.

---

I am using Python 3.7.4 x64 on Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a reference leak.

Using this `sitecustomize.py` to print the total references counts of objects in Python and a debug build of Python to access `sys.gettotalrefcount()` (it doesn't exist in the release build):

```
import sys
try:
    sys.gettotalrefcount()
    class __refs:
        def __str__(self):
            return '[{} refs]\n>>> '.format(sys.gettotalrefcount())
    sys.ps1 = __refs()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

This shows a leak.  Note that there is some caching in the REPL going on, and `_` holds a reference to the last return value, so I run the function more than once to see a trend:

```
>>> from ctypes import *  # hit enter a couple times to get a stable read
[74186 refs]
>>>
[74187 refs]
>>>
[74187 refs]
>>> s=create_string_buffer(1<<30);del s  # create and delete, stable reading
[74238 refs]
>>> s=create_string_buffer(1<<30);del s
[74238 refs]
>>> s=create_string_buffer(1<<30);del s
[74238 refs]
>>> s=create_string_buffer(1<<30);s=cast(s,c_void_p);del s  # create/cast/delete, leak of 5 references
[74244 refs]
>>> s=create_string_buffer(1<<30);s=cast(s,c_void_p);del s
[74249 refs]
>>> s=create_string_buffer(1<<30);s=cast(s,c_void_p);del s
[74254 refs]
>>> s=create_string_buffer(1<<30);s=cast(s,c_void_p);del s
[74259 refs]
```

Comment: So should I report this on bugs.python.org?

Comment: @Cubi Sure, add a link to it here and I can add my data to it and track it too.